# getting a unique client id of a firefox addon

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

If there is a unique client id that is assigned to somebody who downloads my addon, how do I get it? I've tried Client.id which I found is experimental (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Client/id). 
If there isn't a unique, stable client id that is assigned to my clients who downloads my addon, how do I assign them one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [browser.runtime.id](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/id):

> A string representing the add-on ID. If the extension specified an ID in its applications manifest.json key, runtime.id will contain that value. Otherwise, runtime.id will contain the ID that was generated for the extension.

Go to `about:debugging` and you will see the IDs of all your installed addons.